# How can I convert string[] to T?

Tags: c#

I have a method like below ↓

```
    static T GetItemSample<T>() where T : new ()
    {
        if (T is string[])
        {
          string[] values = new string[] { "col1" , "col2" , "col3"};
          Type elementType = typeof(string);
          Array array = Array.CreateInstance(elementType, values.Length);
          values.CopyTo(array, 0);
          T obj = (T)(object)array;
          return obj;
        }
        else
        {
          return new T();
        }
　 }
```

There is an error when I invoke the method like ↓

```
string[] ret = GetItemSample<string[]>();
```

Is anybody could told me how to use the method when the param is string[] ?

thks .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first error (`'T' is a 'type parameter' but is used like a 'variable'`) is that `T is string[]` won't work. You could use `typeof(string[])==typeof(T)`

The second error (`'string[]' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'UserQuery.GetItemSample<T>()'`) is that `string[]` has no default constructor but the generic constraint requires it to have one.

```
static T GetItemSample<T>()
    {
        if (typeof(string[])==typeof(T))
        {
          string[] values = new string[] { "col1" , "col2" , "col3"};
          Type elementType = typeof(string);
          Array array = Array.CreateInstance(elementType, values.Length);
          values.CopyTo(array, 0);
          T obj = (T)(object)array;
          return obj;
        }
        else
        {
          return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        }
　 }
```

The disadvantage of this code is that it throws an error at runtime if `T` has no default constructor instead of at compile-time.

Answer (score 1):

Your method must be like

```
static T GetItemSample<T>(T[] obj)
```

or

```
static T GetItemSample<T>(T obj)
```